# Setting correct options for grid using EPSG 3004 in QGIS 3.10?

Tags: coordinates, layouts, grids-graticules

I would like to produce in QGIS a layout with the grid.
My project is based on EPSG 3004.
I manage to use the grid tool until a certain point, because the coordinates seem very messy.

What can I do in other to improve the output?

Beside the segment not being regular (I would like the segment to start at the various angles), the coordinates are not coherent.
I attached the current settings.

[image: map]

[image: setting 1]

[image: setting 2]

[image: setting 3]

Answer (score 0):

You have a projection in metres but are displaying it as degrees minutes and seconds. So, either change the projection of your grid to 4326 or change the units to decimal.